# Installed C# application write permissions

Tags: c#, xml, save

I have a C# application that has been installed but this program needs to be able to read and write xml. I tested the installed program and it can read the xml if it is there but it gets an exception when the program closes.

Could someone help me.

The current way I create xml is like this:

```
private void SaveQuickLinks(List<QuickLinksData> QuickLinks)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("QuickLinks.xml");
            doc.RemoveAll();


            XmlElement Root = doc.CreateElement("", "QuickLinksList", "");
            doc.AppendChild(Root);

            foreach (QuickLinksData QuickLink in QuickLinks)
            {
                //Create New QuickLink
                XmlElement LinkElement = doc.CreateElement("", "QuickLink", "");
                Root.AppendChild(LinkElement);

                //Create Element With QuickLink Name
                XmlElement QuickLinkName = doc.CreateElement("", "LinkName", "");
                XmlText LinkName = doc.CreateTextNode(QuickLink.Link_Name);
                QuickLinkName.AppendChild(LinkName);
                LinkElement.AppendChild(QuickLinkName);

                //Create Element with QuickLink Link
                XmlElement QuickLinkURL = doc.CreateElement("", "LinkURL", "");
                XmlText LinkURL = doc.CreateTextNode(QuickLink.Link_URL);
                QuickLinkURL.AppendChild(LinkURL);
                LinkElement.AppendChild(QuickLinkURL);
            }

            //File.SetAttributes("QuickLinks.xml", FileAttributes.Normal);
            //doc.Save("QuickLinks.xml");

            using (var file = new FileStream("QuickLinks.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                doc.Save("QuickLinks.xml");
            }
        }
```

I need the be able to over write this every time my application closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every C# program has the permissions of the user that is executing it, it is not managed on the application level. Check that the user that executes the program has write access to the location where you are saving the file to (which seems to be the working directory of the program - usually the folder where the binaries are, but that might be different).

E.g. if you installed it to `C:\Programme Files`, and are running it as a normal user, then it might not have write access to this directory (you need Admin rights by default). Consider moving the file to e.g. `%APPDATA%`

Comment: You are using "using" so it will close the file-steam ok..What Exception is thrown? are you getting a System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access..(file name) ?
if you are then Grzenio is right.

Answer (score 0):

Check the access permissions and grant write permissions to users accessing this file.
When you install c# application by default it goes to **C:\Program Files\'Your application'** and it is not a good practice to create/overwrite files present under C:\Program Files.

I have faced this issue and came up with this solution for my application

1. Create a directory with application name under your user profile (**C:\Users\'Application Name'** for windows 7). User will have full access to his user profile
2. Place this file in that directory and get the file path using the following code

   string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Application Name"), "File Name");